# How would we use grep to search munltiple patterns?

Tags: grep

I have a situation like the following:
I have 4 patterns like:

```
home page            -- can be in any line
libraries and STLs   -- can be in any line
Windows  Cygwin      -- These two words should be on the same line
xmlwriter.cpp        -- can be in any line
```

How can I write grep so that grep should return the result only if all the patterns are present in the input file?

Comment: Tip: Grep on grep's output

Comment: specifically:  `grep 'pat1' file |grep 'pat2'|grep 'pat3'|grep 'pat4'`

Comment: I am using grep in windows 7

Comment: @Kent: that will not work since it will search pat1,pat2,pat3 and pat4 in the same line for a successful match

Comment: My doubt is if there is any single line command or I should use batch program. If I should use a batch file, please help me out since I don't have much idea about batch programming

Comment: @legends2k: Could you please explain?

Comment: @Smij01 you want `grep -E '(pat1|pat2|pat3|pat4)' file`?

Comment: Follow @Kent's suggestion.

Comment: @Kent The command you gave throws the error "'libraries' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."  What should be the exact out of grep -E '(pat1|pat2|pat3|pat4)' file? I am using Windows 7 and I want to search a few number of patterns in some files and I want grep to give only those files which is having all the keywords in the same file.

Comment: @Smij01 sorry I don't have windows system and not familiar with windows either. cannot test for you...